# Using django-admin in deployed project

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working with django, and I would like to use django-admin to manage certain things of my site, including the mantainance of the database.

Can I use it once the project is deployed or should I consider other options? I have searched for options but I didnt find anything. Leaving the admin site like www.mysite.com/admin I dont think is an option because of security issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django admin is exactly what you should be using to administrate (hence the name) your site after deployment. What are the security issues behind www.mysite.com/admin? You need a user account with staff privileges to access the admin area.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, how can I prevent everybody from accessing mysite.com/admin ? I dont want visitors to see that. I have read that its recommended to disable the adminsite in deployed projects...

Comment: By all means you can disable the admin site if you're not using it. There are no security vulnerabilities with the django-admin site that I know of, so provided you're not giving your credentials out you're fine. If you're really that concerned you could always limit access to the admin url's in your nginx config or apache htaccess or whatever you're using.

Comment: [here](http://www.davidfischer.name/2011/02/securing-django-in-production/) is a good article that covers some of this.